# References and Pointers and parameter passing with const

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

Somehow, for the life of me, I cannot ever understand references.  I have this `queue` class with the method:

```
void push(const T& item);
```

I'm now trying to put something into the queue (this is a very contrived example):

```
class my_class { };

void dispatch(const my_class* item)
{
    my_queue<my_class*> queue;
    queue.push(item);
}

// ...

auto x = new my_class;
dispatch(x);
```

I get errors about converting from `const my_class*` to `my_class *const&`.  I've tried `&item`, casting the `item`, but none of them make the compiler happy.  What is the correct way to do this?  Should my `queue` be of `my_class` instead of `my_class*`?  Another possibility is that my `push` parameter type is incorrect as well...

Comment: `*item` won't work because my queue's `push` after the template processing is expecting `my_class*&` (I didn't include the `const`s because their ordering always confuses me).  `*item` would get it to be a `my_class&`.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. But instead of making the parameter type `const my_class*`, change the parameter of the function itself to `my_class*`

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it -- my queue needs to be of type `const my_class*` to match my `dispatch` parameter type.  Let me know if there's a better way....

Comment: Or refactor the answer to a more "answerish" form or edit your question with the additional data and thoughts.